# How do I blend multiple dataframes that contain string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframe like this:
`df1`:

```
id  c1
1   aa
2   aa
3   xx
4   xx
5   yy
```

`df2`:

```
id  c1
1   aa
2   xx
3   aa
4   yy
5   xx
```

`df3`:

```
id  c1
1   xx
2   xx
3   aa
4   yy
5   aa
```

I want to create a new dataframe `df4` based on the following conditions:

- `df4` will contain value that is of majority (example: two datasframe says the value should be `aa where id = 1`, so `df4` will contain `aa` at id 1
- If all the dataframes contain unique value, then `df1`'s value will be choosen (example at id 5, all 3 dataframe contain different value i.e yy,xx,aa but `df1` contain `yy` so yy will be choosen

Expected output:

```
`df4`:

    id  c1
    1   aa
    2   xx
    3   aa
    4   yy
    5   yy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should achieve what you want. We try and find the `mode` of a given row and if that fails we grab the item from the first dataframe. Then we apply this function row-wise to the concatenated dataframes to achieve the desired result.

```
from statistics import StatisticsError, mode

def maybe_mode(row):
    try:
        v = mode(row)
    except StatisticsError:
        v = row.iloc[0]
    return v



df4 = pd.DataFrame(df1.id)

df4['c1'] = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).c1.apply(maybe_mode, axis=1)

print(df4)

   id  c1
0   1  aa
1   2  xx
2   3  aa
3   4  yy
4   5  yy
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I totally forgot about mode. I just wanted to calculate mode, hehe. I should have given more focus in maths class

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of this now, but this is not a very good option. 
Since, we need to modify  all of the code if we add more dataframe
-Time confusing, because of two loops

```
col = df1['surface'].unique()
df4 = df1
for i in range (len(col)):
    for j in range (len(df1)):
        if (df1['surface'][j] == col[i] and df2['surface'][j] == col[i]):
            df4['surface'][j] = col[i]
        elif (df2['surface'][j] == col[i] and df3['surface'][j] == col[i]):
            df4['surface'][j] = col[i]
        elif (df1['surface'][j] == col[i] and df3['surface'][j] == col[i]):
            df4['surface'][j] = col[i]
        elif (df2['surface'][j] == col[i] and df2['surface'][j] != df3['surface'][j]):
            df4['surface'][j] = col[i]
```

Comment: don't do this, you should avoid when possible looping over a dataframe using `for-loops`

Comment: Yeah exactly, it is taking too long